# Does removing a user from an organization revoke their personal access tokens?

Tags: azure-devops

As the question suggests, does removing a user from a VSTS / Azure DevOps organization also revoke any Personal Access Tokens? I assume they do but I have not been able to find any documentation for this from Microsoft.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No, based on my test if you remove users from an organization it will remove their permissions permanently, that means you cannot access the organization anymore.

But the existing PATs will not be revoked automatically. If you add the specific user back, you can still see the PATs under `Security`.

(Check that by navigating to `https://{Account}.visualstudio.com/_usersSettings/tokens`)

[image]

Comment: I can only see a 404 when attempting to hit that page. Is there somewhere else where I can see this information?

Comment: @user7100889 404 means not found, make sure you have the correct permission to access that page. Also check that if the user was removed from the organization. If the issue persists please share the screenshot and error message here for troubleshoot.